# json_encode of object results in intended callback wrapped in quotes

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a PHP Object that contains some callbacks.

```
<?php
$configs = array(
    'callback'    => 'mycallback'
);

// Encode array to json format
$json = json_encode( $configs);

// Remove quotes around callback value ONLY.
$configs = str_replace( ..., ..., $json );

<!-- Output as Global var for jQuery code use -->
<script async>
    var _configs = <?php echo $configs; ?>;
</script>
```

This doesn't work because json_encode interprets the callback value as a string and rightfully so, but is it acceptable to remove the quotes surrounding the callback value after encoding the object to a JSON string?

So that after json_encode:

```
{ "callback": "mycallback" }
```

and after removing the quotes:

```
{ "callback": mycallback }
```

I don't see an issue with removing those quotes since the JSON is still valid, but assuming it is valid I'm not having any luck removing the quotes around the callback name.

Does anyone know of a better solution or how to remove those quotes?

Comment: removing those quotes make it not valid JSON.

Comment: I think your problem lies in the JS code, and addressing that will be far more productive that hacking your PHP to return invalid JSON.

Comment: @DanielA.White I didn't know it made the JSON invalid to remove the quotes. I wouldn't want to do that... @Sammitch is probably correct, but I'm not finding anything on how to code the JS to use a string as a callback. I see how to do it with an inline function using `new Function(...)` but how can this be done with quoted callbacks?